# Guaranteeing that the numerical approximation to $B = K^{-T}K^{-1}$ is positive definite in Zhang's algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

In Zhang's Algorithm to determine the intrinsic parameter matrix $K$ (see [here](https://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/html/teaching/msr2-2020/sse2-14-calibration-zhang.pdf) for slides talking about this), we instead compute the matrix $B = K^{-T}K^{-1}$ since we obtain a linear system in the variables of that matrix. The general idea is that once we obtain $B$, we use the Cholesky decomposition to decompose $B$ into the form $LL^T$ and the uniqueness of this decomposition upto signs of the columns and the fact that $K$ is positive on the diagonal allows us to retrieve $K$.

However in practice, we cannot solve the system of equations exactly, and the suggested method is to take the least squares optimal solution of the linear system by picking the vector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue.

My issue is how this guarantees that the $B$ we obtain is positive definite. Should we perform some sort of projection to ensure this is the case or will this just hold in general (or does it not matter)? The Cholesky decomposition requires that the matrix be at least positive semi-definite (and I belive uniqueness requires positive definite).

EDIT: I think there is some confusion in my wording, so I would like to be a bit more precise. The matrix $K$ is unknown and we wish to identify it. We instead look for the matrix $B = K^{-T}K^{-1}$ by solving a linear system and them applying the Cholesky decomposition to find $K$. However we don't solve the linear system exactly for $B$ (due to noise and real world errors) and we only obtain a (least-squares) approximation $\widehat{B}$ from which we calculate $K$. My question is why this matrix $\widehat{B}$ has to be positive definite.

Comment: By its form, $K^{-T}K^{-1}$ is positive semidefinite.  Also, $K$ needs to be square and invertible for $K^{-1}$ to exist.  Thus $K^{-T}K^{-1}$ will be invertible and positive definite.

Comment: Numerically, $K$ might be nearly singular.  If that happens, you're in trouble.

Comment: I'm aware that the ideal theoretical $B$ is positive definite, but my point is that the matrix we recover from the data need not be (or does it need to be?) and how we should handle that situation.

Comment: If $B$ is numerically singular, then you can use the SVD (or the eigenvalue decomposition since the matrix is symmetric) dropping the 0 singular values (eigenvalues) to find a minimum norm least squares solution.  Whether that is useful for your purposes is a higher-level question, and you haven't really provided the context for that.

Comment: My issues are not numerical but theoretical. B doesn't have to be singular to not be positive definite. For example $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is not positive definite even though it is invertible. Positive definite requires all the eigenvalues to be positive and I don't see why the minimum norm least squares solution for B will actually have all positive eigenvalues (as opposed to the normal some positive some negative). The Zhang method requires finding this matrix B and then extracting the camera matrix K from it using the Cholesky decomposition which needs +ve definite.

Comment: The issue is that by solving a system of equations that B satisfies to find B, we are not adding in the condition that B is positive definite (that wouldn't be a linear condition). This means that the answer we get for B, $\widehat{B}$ need not be positive definite. So my question is whether that is reasonable and if there are known methods to handle it.

Comment: You computed $B$ by finding $K$ and then $K^{-1}$.  If $K$ is is numerically and exactly nonsingular, than $B$ will be exactly nonsingular and positive definite.  If $K$ is numerically or actually singular, then your algorithm is broken in a more fundamental way- a solution to that problem will not simply "ensure that B is positive definite" but will have to do something besides solving a system of equations involving $B$.

Comment: Your comments above are contradictory.  I think you agree that in theory, the $B$ matrix will always be positive definite and nonsingular, but then you bring back an example $B$ matrix is not positive definite.    I also think we agree that in practice the $B$ matrix might be numerically singular.  Are you asking what to do when $B$ is numerically singular, or are you asking why $B$ is theoretically positive definite and nonsingular?

Comment: I think you misunderstand, and no, there is no contradiction. The matrix K is unknown, and so the singularity or not of K is irrelevant here. We wish to determine K and we do so by determining B instead. However, the method of determining K from B requires that B is positive definite, while the method doesn't guarantee that the B obtained is positive definite since we are unable to exactly solve the system of equations involving the coefficients of B and are only able to pick a minimum norm solution.

Comment: There is another example in computer vision, the eight point algorithm, where we wish to determine an essential matrix but we cannot guarantee the matrix we obtain from the equations will satisfy desired conditions. The solution is to take the least squares solution and project it onto the space of essential matrices (see [here](https://vision.in.tum.de/_media/teaching/ss2019/mvg2019/material/multiviewgeometry5.pdf)). I am asking if this is similar.

Comment: Let's make an even simpler analogy. What you are asking is like "how do I ensure that $A$ is invertible when solving a linear system $Ax=b$". There are various possible answers, including "you can't; sometimes your input matrices are singular and the problem has no solution" and "it depends; where does $A$ come from?". But ultimately the question that you need to ask yourself is another: "what other problem do I want to solve instead if $A$ is singular in my input data, since the problem $Ax=b$ has no solution?". And that leads to interesting new math such as linear least squares.

Comment: Yes you're right I'm asking exactly for the new math. This algorithm is used in OpenCV and other commercial software, so surely there is some reasoning involved here. I would like to know and understand it.

Also invertibility is an open condition and the set of invertible matrices is dense but positive definite matrices are much more sparse.

Comment: Also singularity is a degenerate configuration, while being not positive definite is not (if you have n eigenvalues, most likely there will be two with opposing signs). The more accurate analogy is that we require that a matrix to be singular, why should it be so? If it is not, what do we do?

Comment: I believe the crux of the problem is how $B$ is defined.  Although you related the $3\times 3$ matrices $B$ and $K$, my reading of the slides you linked is that $B$ is computed in an early step and then $K$ is derived from $B$.  The slides reference a 1998 "Microsoft Technical Report" which Zhengyou Zhang has posted [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr98-71.pdf).

Comment: Yes, when we use this algorithm in the real world, we wish to identify $K$ but we can only obtain an easy linear system of equations $AB = 0$ for $B = K^{-T} K^{-1}$ using data points from images. However generally these data points will be noisy, and so we do not compute this B exactly. We find a least squares approximate solution to that system by minimizing $|AB|^2$ subject to $|B| = 1$ using vector corresponding to the least singular value of A as usual.

The issue is that to recover K from this approximation to B, we require that it is positive definite.

Comment: And yes, I tried reading the paper. The algorithm suggests first doing the above ^ method to find a guess for K and then using Levenberg Marquardt to refine the guess. I think my issue still remains, but since the author doesn't mention it, maybe it doesn't come up in practice?

Comment: Since we are dealing with $3\times 3$ matrices, I would hope it wouldn't be too much trouble to explain your construction of $B$ (or $\hat B$) in the body of your Question.  Without that information I don't see how anyone could make progress on the issue of whether $B$ will necessarily or likely be positive definite.  Of course the Cholesky computation would tell us with little computational expense.

Comment: There is nothing special about the construction of B. We just form a system of equations involving the coefficients of B (which is symmetric and hence has 5 dof) and we solve it. see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxbQ-F8u08U&ab_channel=BehnamAsadi) for the type of system. It is just a regular system with no special properties (i.e every possible linear system is possible).

Maybe there is more structure that I am unaware of, but I have looked at multiple sources and I don't know.

Comment: To be honest using that $K$ just seems a bad parametrization that can cause trouble. What do you use its entries for? Maybe there is a different way to structure your computation without relying on $K$ at all?